# why does the kill function man page shows two header sys/types.h and signal.h

Tags: c, header-files, manpage

`man 2 kill` - The man page for kill function in C
shows two header file in SYNOPSIS -

1. #include <sys/types.h>
2. #include <signal.h>

When I used the kill function in my c program it compiled perfectly by `only including the signal.h file`. 
Is it important to include all the #include mentioned in the `synopsis`?
What's the purpose of `sys/types.h` in the kill above?

Comment: Once upon quite a long time ago, POSIX said that `<sys/types.h>` was needed, though the X/Open standard and the SVID on which it was based didn't require it — and most actual implementations did not need it either (it was, in effect, included automatically).  For over a decade, the `#include <sys/types.h>` has not been needed even on Linux, but the manuals haven't been changed.  That's not an official position; it is a de facto observation, though.

Comment: POSIX 1997: [`kill()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/kill.html) — requires `<sys/types.h>` too.  By contrast, POSIX 2004: [`kill()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html) — does not require `<sys/types.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `sys/types.h` to use `pid_t` and it's optionally. But `signal.h` allows you to use `kill` (and others functions), signal constant etc. So `#include <signal.h>` is necessarily for using `kill`.

Comment: "native Linux syscall, so you don't need any includes to use it." is wrong and bad advice. First because you're calling the library function `kill` and not the syscall directly, second because calling a function in C89 without a prototype causes an implicit declaration of that function (as a function taking some unspecified number of args, returning int). A modern compiler will warn you against doing that (since it is probably not what you meant, and may lead to very unfortunate surprises).

Comment: @Hasturkun thanks for reply, edited answer to make it correct

Comment: But when you open a man page for a c function it may list say 4 header file in the synopsis. How are we going to find out which one to use? Like in above you said that **types.h** will be required when using **pid_t** since my code is not using it so I don't need it. What's the general practice? If I want to use a function should I by default include all the header files mentioned in the synopsis? Is that a good coding practice?

Comment: Yes, you might as well just include all of them.  There's no real harm in doing so.